# Using header information in a text file to organise a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with the following format:

```
_data

loop_

_rlnName
_rlndatainfo1
_rlndatainfo2
_rlndatainfo3
Name    datainfo1    datainfo2    datainfo3
```

Where the *data and loop* can be ignored, anything with _rln is a title and then all the data is in rows below.

There can be a random number of columns and titles but this is the general layout of the file. The data is not always in the same order but will always be organised correctly in that each row in titles is the column number in the data field. For this reason I want to write a general function that I can always use for dealing with these files where I chuck the data into a dataframe and loop through the titles heading each of my dataframe columns with the correct title. This will let me just index whichever columns I need and will make processing much faster.

So far I am just trying to loop through the titles so I can get them in a list to title the dataframe and then figure out where to start the data row from.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('text.txt')

titles = []

for line in data.index:
    if '_rln' in data.iloc[line]:
        titles.append(data.iloc[line])

print(titles)
```

Currently this is creating an empty list. I must be doing something stupid, I have put this off for so long because I don't have much experience with pandas so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the `titles` and `line number` of last `_rln`
then create the data frame as below

```
import pandas as pd

titles = []
lastrlnLine = 0;
with open("test3.csv","r") as fi:
    for num, ln in enumerate(fi, 1):
        if ln.startswith("_rln"):
            lastrlnLine = num
            titles.append(ln[4:].rstrip())
data = pd.read_csv('test3.csv', delimiter='\t', skiprows=lastrlnLine, header=None, names=titles)
print(data)
```

Comment: skiprows=lastrlnLine+1 and then this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields (column names) are the same in all files are the same you could do something like the following.

```py
import pandas
df = None
titles = list()

with open('test1.csv') as handle:
    while True:
        line = handle.readline()
        if line.startswith('_rln'):
            titles.append(line)
            continue
        if line.startswith('Name'):
            df = pandas.read_csv(handle)
            break
```

If they are not the same then you should be able to turn the code above into a function where you can change the `startswith` line. To the name of the expected field names.

Comment: If your `_rn*` rows always number 4 then yes, this will work.  But not if you expect this to work with arbitrary number of `_rn*` rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


titles = []
data = open('txt.txt')
datalines = data.readlines()
counter = 0
for line in range(len(datalines) - 1):
    if '_rln' in datalines[line]:
        var = datalines[line]
        var = var.strip(' \n')
        titles.append(var)
        counter = line

dataframe = pd.read_csv('txt.txt', delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=counter+1, header=None, names=titles)
```

Thank you to Prince Francis I had almost made it to the same stage as this answer but couldn't figure out how to get the counter working. It turns out I was being super silly. Everything in Prince Francis code works except the skiprows needs an addition of 1.